# MailKit SMTPUTF8 error

Tags: c#, smtp, mailkit

I'm using MimeKit and MailKit together to send off e-mails through an SMTP server. Every now and then, though, I've got a server that throws back an error at me:

```
The SMTP server does not support the SMTPUTF8 extension
```

Obviously, I'd like to stop these errors from occurring. Is there a way in MimeKit to disable the SMTPUTF8 extension on either the SmtpClient, MimeMessage, or MimeEntity?

I fear I'm asking the wrong question, or asking for a solution in the wrong place. If anybody can add clarification to a possibly poorly worded question, please let me know.

Here's how I'm sending:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.Connect("server", port);
        // I've got reasons to remove this.
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Pokemon Exception handling right here
        // for the sake of showing what I'm doing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One or more of the email addresses in your list of recipients (or the sender) has a unicode address (and I don't mean the "display name" contains unicode characters, I mean that the "x@y.com" part contains unicode characters that require the SMTP server to support the SMTPUTF8 extension in order to work).

For example, you might be trying to send to an email address such as `日本語@日本語.jp`. Note that traditionally, only ASCII-based email addresses were allowed and SMTP servers that do not support the SMTPUTF8 extension cannot handle email addresses that are non-ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I can guarantee that the e-mail addresses themselves do not have any UTF-8 characters (I'm looking at the list of e-mail addresses currently). I'm using InternetAddress.TryParse() which has an overload for the ParserOptions to use. I noticed that the [Default](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/e4ef905a668c10874de4239dcfd60deb610309f6/MimeKit/ParserOptions.cs#L138) ParserOptions uses UTF8 for encoding. Would using a ParserOptions instance that doesn't have UTF-8 as the encoding selection work instead?

Comment: No, that's not the problem. UTF8 is just being used by the parser to convert raw bytes into a `string` (all `string`s are unicode in .NET, but the question is whether or not it contains non-ASCII when converting from `string` into `byte[]`). To give you a better idea of what is failing, at least one of your email addresses is returning `true` for the `IsInternational` property: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/MailboxAddress.cs#L185

Comment: Try running a similar loop over all of the characters in each of your email addresses and see which character is causing it to return true. If they look like ASCII to you, then it might be that one of the characters is an invisible unicode character or it could be a unicode character that *looks* like a similar ASCII character and you are just unable to tell the difference due to the font (it can be incredibly difficult to tell or even impossible, especially if you don't know what to look for).

Comment: Oh wow. That's a really nice property. Assuming that returns true, can I simply convert from UTF-8 to ASCII and be done with it or can I not be that naive?

Comment: Ahhh, IsInternational is only on MailboxAddress. Should I also be performing the check on instances I'm making into InternetAddress? I would logically think so, but, I don't know the RFCs as well as you do.

Comment: `InternetAddress` is just a base class for `MailboxAddress` and `GroupAddress` (and I doubt you are seeing any `GroupAddresses` since they are obsolete in the internet world at this point). A quick way to iterate over all `MailboxAddresses` in an `InternetAddressList` is to just use the `Mailboxes` property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104207/discussion-between-jstedfast-and-adam-sears).

Comment: @jstedfast, I had a similar problem where the recipient email address had a special character in it before the @ sign, eg coordinación@test.XXXX.com, in such a case the mail relay fails with an smtputf8 exception if the actual mail server has the support.

Comment: Does client.Capabilities have the UTF8 flag set? If it does, then you won't get an exception that says that the server doesn't. Otherwise, send me a protocol log and I'll take a look.

Comment: Yep, you were right,  the  server doesn't support SMTPUTF8 extension, i changed the address to punycode to make it work, not happy with it, bit don't see any other way out.

Comment: I was aware of punycode working for domains, but not local-parts of addresses.